# date_format parsing not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does my date comparison not work,

mostly returning either all dates or none

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y - %m - %d'),'2013 - 01 - 10'  
FROM signature,files 
WHERE files.id = signature.id and instruction like '%BM%' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d') < date('2013-01-10') ;
```

doesn't return result. when I change to `DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d') < '2013-01-10'` same and even this `DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y %m %d')` didn't work

Comment: Which format of date have you used?

Comment: time is datetime format

Comment: they look the same when i print them out both '2013 02 10' or both '2013-10-10'

Comment: Add your table structure, sample input data and the desired output data to understand the problem in detail

Comment: You don't convert numbers to strings before comparing them, do you? Then, why do you do it for dates?

Comment: Any answer that puts a function call over `time` for the comparison will ignore indices, even if it otherwise returns correct results.  What's wrong with making the input data a datetime and comparing the data that way?

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT` function returns a string with character set and collation.I am not sure if you will get correct comparison using `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
  Select DATE(time),'2013 - 01 - 10'  
  FROM signature,files 
  WHERE files.id = signature.id and instruction like '%BM%' 
  AND Date(time) < Date('2013-01-10') ;
```

or use [STR_TO_DATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013,05,01','%Y,%m,%d');
```